# Using Bitcoin for Bond Certificates

Tags: contracts, colored-coins, stocks

I have a product that is in development and I want to allow people to buy something like bonds to raise money for the project. I was thinking to develop my own protocol for defining these bond certificates but first I want to check if Bitcoin provides something for it.

Some of the requirements are:

- Bonds are sold sequentially and have serial numbers. Each subsequent bond is a little bit (a fraction of a penny) more expensive than the previous bond sold.
- Bonds have to be splitable just like share splits.
- People should be able to buy anonymously and receive a bond certificate without providing an email, or any identifiable addresses.
- Should be able to validate bond certificates with a public key.
- At the bond's maturity time, the shareholder (bond owner) should be able to claim that they own in with a private key.

Are there any Bitcoin features to help with this?

Thanks!

Comment: "Each subsequent bond is a little bit (a fraction of a penny) more expensive than the previous bond sold." - this is up to the market to decide. Apart from that what you are describing is a blockchain with a financial token. ie you are describing an alt coin based on bitcoin (probably).

Answer (score 1):

[OpenAssets](https://github.com/OpenAssets) and [CounterParty](http://counterparty.io/) are the most similar projects I can think of, but I'm sure it doesn't have all of the features you are looking for. You may also be interested in Overstock's Medici project.